# PYTHON - Remove tuple from list if contained in another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = [('4', 35.26), ('1', 48.19), ('5', 90.0), ('3', 90.0)]
```

tuple[0] is an item_ID

tuple[1] is an angle

I have a list of item_IDs I want to remove/ignore from the list:

```
ignore_IDs = [5, 3]
```

I need to find the smallest angle in the list_of_tuples as long as its ID is not in ignore_IDs.

This is used in a function where the angles change and the IDs to ignore change.

Can anyone help me out?

Apologies if explained badly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do, if I didn't misunderstood:

```
min([t[1] for t in list_of_tuples if int(t[0]) not in ignore_IDs])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` with a lambda to accomplish this, too:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in map(str, ignore_IDs), list_of_tuples))
[('4', 35.26), ('1', 48.19)]
```

Note: the `map(str, ignore_IDs)` line was used because you had conflicting types between your tuple IDs and the IDs to be ignored.

One suggestion: if you have lots of IDs you want to ignore, I would recommend using a hashable object, like a dictionary or set. Membership lookups for hashable objects are `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` for lists.

Answer (score 0):

min function supports a key. you can use a lambda function in the key to get the answer you want.

see this example

```
min(list_of_tuples, key = lambda (i,x): x if int(i) not in ignore_IDs else '')[1]
```

this will result in the smallest angle with item id not in ignore id

```
35.26
```