# How to delete an element from a tuple of list

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble that how to delete the elements of the "stopWord" from a tuple list,the code as follows:

```
wordFreqDict = {'apple':20,'orange':30,'show':40,'he':100}
stopWord = ['he','she']
listofTuples = sorted(wordsFreqDict.items() , reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Thank you in advance！

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYTHON - Remove tuple from list if contained in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049968/python-remove-tuple-from-list-if-contained-in-another-list)

Comment: spelling mistake on this line wordsFreqDict.items() but actual is wordFreqDict

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
wordFreqDict = {'apple':20,'orange':30,'show':40,'he':100}
stopWord = ['he','she']
listofTuples = sorted(wordFreqDict.items() , reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
print('before removing first tuple of list of tuples :', listofTuples)
listofTuples.remove(listofTuples[0])
print('after removed first tuple of list of tuples :', listofTuples)
```